# Почему не работает вложенный цикл в Google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

У меня есть csv файл который я принимаю в виде текста, далее привожу его в вид массивов. После я пробегаю циклом по массиву данных csv и массиву названий строк. Но не могу вставлять значения потому что он просто отказывается работать и не выдает никакой ошибки.введите сюда код Уже всю голову сломал. Не понимаю как еще могу

```
const to_csv = CSVToArray(response.getContentText(), ";")

const column = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF']
  
var e = 0
var i = 0
while (e < to_csv.length) {
    
  var iter = to_csv[e]
  while (i < iter) {
    var cell = `${column[i]}`;    
    ss.getRange(`${cell}1`).activate().setValue(to_csv[e][i]);
    i++
    };
  e++
  };
```

Цитата

Не понимаю что делать

Comment: `CSVToArray` ? Есть же `Utilities.parseCsv()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете просто вставить данные в Таблицу вот так

```
const to_csv = CSVToArray(response.getContentText(), ";");
ss.getRange(1,1,to_csv.length, to_csv[0].length).setValues(to_csv);
```

И да, не используйте `setValue` в циклах -- это серьезное нарушение концепции Apps Script и вообще облачных сервисов.

Но я бы сделал вот так

```
const to_csv = Utilities.parseCsv(response.getContentText(), ';');
ss.getRange(1,1,to_csv.length, to_csv[0].length).setValues(to_csv);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const to_csv = CSVToArray(response.getContentText(), ";");
const column = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF'];

var e = 0;
while (e < to_csv.length) {
  var iter = to_csv[e];
  var i = 0; // сбросить для каждой строки 
  while (i < iter.length) { // iter это число или массив?
    var cell = `${column[i]}`;
    ss.getRange(`${cell}1`).activate().setValue(to_csv[e][i]);
    i++;
  }
  e++;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]